# What is the best way to add a user to cognito user pool after a federated identity login?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

While using Android SDK Cognito does not add users automatically to the user pool if user logins with a 3rd parth identity provider like Google or Facebook.

What is the best way to do this? Should I register user from Android app?
After successful login I can look for the user with the related email and that I can show a user information for to let them enter their info.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me - let the users authenticate using Cognito (not FB or Google directly). The Cognito logon page can  further delegate the social network authentication and adding users to the user pool

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/login-endpoint.html

(I know this is the web endpoint)

> I can show a user information for to let them enter their info

the id_token received after logon contains the user email if you request it, you don't need to add users to the pool to get this information

Comment: Hi, I do the same, but Mobile Hub SDK does not add user to user pool. This is what I'm trying to do actually.